# ACRU4 PercentRiparianInfestation

Tags: hydrology, models

One of the routines that I am interested in exploring further is the option of including a riparian zone within the Agricultural Catchments Research Unit (ACRU4) model. Once I add the riparian zone to the model, there are a few options available that need to be populated. While most are self explanatory, I am unsure about how the percent riparian infestation option actually works.

Answer (score 1):

Typically riparian zones in ACRU are configured to receive baseflow from upslope HRUs.  If we consider 3 scenarios:
(1)    PercentRiparianInfestation=0%: there is no alien vegetation in the riparian zone and all the baseflow from upslope HRU will reach the river.
(2)    PercentRiparianInfestation=50%: half the riparian zone is infested with alien vegetation, and thus the riparian zone subsoil horizon will be drier, and up to 50% of the baseflow from the upslope HRUs will be retained in the riparian zone subsoil horizon and the remainder will reach the river.
(3)    PercentRiparianInfestation=100%: the whole riparian zone is infested with alien vegetation, and thus the riparian zone subsoil horizon will be even drier, and up to 100% of the baseflow from the upslope HRUs will be retained in the  riparian zone subsoil horizon and the remainder will reach the river.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).